# MySql stored procedure parameter not found in the collection using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute and call the stored procedure that I made. Upon calling the stored procedure, it throws an error.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_SalesInsertNewOrder`(   
   IN spTransNo INT,
   IN spProdId INT,
   IN spProdOPrice double,
   IN spProdNPrice double,
   IN spProdQty INT, 
   IN spAmount double,
   IN spRemarks varchar(45),
   OUT spStdID INT
)

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_salestransactiondetail(std_TransNo, std_ProdID, std_OPrice, std_NPrice, std_QtySold, std_AmountSold, std_Remarks) 
    VALUE(spTransNo, spProdId, spProdOPrice, spProdNPrice, spProdQty, spAmount, spRemarks);
    SELECT max(std_PK) INTO spStdID from tbl_salestransactiondetail;    
END
```

and here is my vb.net code:

```
Dim comm As MySqlCommand
        Try                
            connectToDB()
            comm = New MySqlCommand("sp_SalesInsertNewOrder", conn)
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spTransNo", modCurTransNum)
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spProdId", std_ProdId)
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spProdOPrice", std_ProdOPrice)
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spProdNPrice", std_ProdNPrice)
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spProdQty", std_ProdQty)
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spAmount", std_Amount)
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spRemarks", std_Remarks)                
            comm.Parameters("@spSTDId").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            If comm.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
                modCurOSNo = comm.Parameters("@spSTDId").Value
                MessageBox.Show("Order has been successfully ADDED!", "Sales Transaction", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

            End If
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Error on modInsertNewOrder() function : " & ex.Message, "Sales Transaction", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Finally
            conn.Dispose()
        End Try
```

error from this line:

```
comm.Parameters("@spSTDId").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
```

> Parameter '@spSTDId' not found in the collection.

Please can you help me to figure it out? Thank you.

Comment: Add Parameter '@spSTDId' to  the collection.!!

Comment: Add `comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spSTId", nothing) `

Comment: @CMedina: you should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...